# Google Vision Api: Differentiate Real Face and A Photo

Tags: android, face-recognition, google-vision

I'm trying develop a facial recognition system. But the issue is it can be by-passed by a photo. I'm using google vision api to detect faces. Is there a way to avoid detecting faces in a photo? Just want to know if there is a real person standing in front of the camera.

Answer (score 3):

The Google Vision API does not support distinguishing between a real face and a face in a photo.

There are a number of ways that you might try to do this in general.  Perhaps the most reliable way would be to use stereo cameras or 3D depth sensors to infer the 3D structure of the face from different viewpoints -- a real face and a photo of a face would obviously have a different 3D structure.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comment. Guess there is no way of achieving this in software wise.